# How to create a new QQuickItem copy from scratch on C++ side with the same properties as an existing one

Tags: qt, qml, qqmlcomponent, qquickitem, qqmlapplicationengine

I have a `QQuickItem` fetched from C++ side like this.

```
QQuickItem * my_item = qmlEngine->rootObjects()[0]->findChild<QQuickItem*>("ItemObjectName");
```

`my_item` is valid & has all the properties set on to it.

**Scenario**
I have **2 windows** which need this `QQuickItem` to be drawn on alterantively. I want to render this `my_item` to a different window. This works perfectly fine as long as I set the Parent of the `my_item` to the other window

```
// the_other_window is a QQuickWindow
QQuickWindow * the_other_window;

// here I set parent
my_item->setParentItem(the_other_window->contentItem());
```

This requires me to do `setParentItem` again back to `my_item`'s original window otherwise it goes invisible on the original window. This is working but gives me unnecessary dependency. Instead I am trying to create a copy of the `QQuickItem` & do a `setParentItem` on that. By copying like this:

```
QQuickItem * item_copy = new QQuickItem(my_item);
```

**Question:**
I want to make `item_copy` as exactly the same as `my_item`.  I learnt that `QQuickItem` is not copyable. So, want to set all properties of `my_item` into `item_copy`. Thus recreating `my_item` from scratch. How can I do this? What properties should I copy primarily? width, height, x, y & what else?

Is there a method to copy all the valid properties into this new one without copying each one by one?

Comment: The current parenting solution makes sense? http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-visualcanvas-visualparent.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To copy all the properties you must use the `metaobject()`, through this we obtain the properties and we can copy them as shown below. Note: not all properties can be written, for this we check with the method `isWritable()`:

```
QQuickItem *copyQQuickItem(QQuickItem *item){
    QQuickItem *item_Copy = new QQuickItem;

    const QMetaObject *mo = item->metaObject();

    for (int i = mo->propertyOffset(); i < mo->propertyCount(); ++i){
        if(mo->property(i).isWritable()){
            const char* name = mo->property(i).name();
            item_Copy->setProperty(name, item->property(name));
        }
    }
    return item_Copy;
}
```

Example:

```
QQuickItem * my_item = engine.rootObjects()[0]->findChild<QQuickItem*>("ItemObjectName");
QQuickItem *item_copy = copyQQuickItem(my_item);

const QMetaObject *mo = my_item->metaObject();

for (int i = mo->propertyOffset(); i < mo->propertyCount(); ++i){
    if(mo->property(i).isWritable()){
        const char* name = mo->property(i).name();
        qDebug()<<name<<my_item->property(name)<<item_copy->property(name);
        Q_ASSERT(my_item->property(name)==item_copy->property(name));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
parent QVariant(QQuickItem*, QQuickRootItem(0x55975cfdf520)) QVariant(QQuickItem*, QQuickRootItem(0x55975cfdf520))
x QVariant(double, 0) QVariant(double, 0)
y QVariant(double, 0) QVariant(double, 0)
z QVariant(double, 0) QVariant(double, 0)
width QVariant(double, 100) QVariant(double, 100)
height QVariant(double, 100) QVariant(double, 100)
opacity QVariant(double, 1) QVariant(double, 1)
enabled QVariant(bool, true) QVariant(bool, true)
visible QVariant(bool, true) QVariant(bool, true)
state QVariant(QString, "") QVariant(QString, "")
baselineOffset QVariant(double, 0) QVariant(double, 0)
clip QVariant(bool, false) QVariant(bool, false)
focus QVariant(bool, false) QVariant(bool, false)
activeFocusOnTab QVariant(bool, false) QVariant(bool, false)
rotation QVariant(double, 0) QVariant(double, 0)
scale QVariant(double, 1) QVariant(double, 1)
transformOrigin QVariant(int, 4) QVariant(int, 4)
smooth QVariant(bool, true) QVariant(bool, true)
antialiasing QVariant(bool, false) QVariant(bool, false)
implicitWidth QVariant(double, 0) QVariant(double, 0)
implicitHeight QVariant(double, 0) QVariant(double, 0)
```

Comment: the copy works great. I accepted the answer for that. but doing a `setParentItem` on `item_copy` dies not display it on the second window. may be thats a separate problem. I tried to call `item_copy->setVisible(true)`. Even that doesn't make `item_copy` show up on the second window. Any suggestions on this please ?